# XML: Webservice returns multiple root elements

Tags: xml, xpath

The web service returns an output similar to this (its by default so there's nothing I can do to change it)

```
<usertask xmlns="..."></usertask><taskid></taskid><blablabla></blablabla></usertask>
<usertask xmlns="..."></usertask><taskid></taskid><blablabla></blablabla></usertask>
<usertask xmlns="..."></usertask><taskid></taskid><blablabla></blablabla></usertask>
```

anyway,  then I try to use xPath query to return the taskid node 
`/usertask/taskid`

it gives an error message that the root element must be well formed. I understand the error message..  but is there a work around to it? as I said the web service cannot be modified..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a root element around before parsing, and parse that.

```
<root>
    <usertask xmlns="..."></usertask><taskid></taskid><blablabla></blablabla></usertask>
    <usertask xmlns="..."></usertask><taskid></taskid><blablabla></blablabla></usertask>
    <usertask xmlns="..."></usertask><taskid></taskid><blablabla></blablabla></usertask>
</root>
```